# Low hot water pressure from cylinder

Tags: water-pressure, hot-water, uk

I have a flat with a cold water tank in the loft space, which feeds into an indirect (coil) heated cylinder in my airing cupboard. Hot water pressure has never been great, but acceptable.

A couple of days ago, the pressure dropped to an extremely low head, whereby hot water barely works at all and quickly drops off to almost nothing.

I have checked that the tank in the loft is still refilling - it is, so there should be enough pressure from that to push the water round.

I have now shut off the inlet to the cylinder and drained it, but I'm not really sure what to look for. **My current thinking is that there's a blockage somewhere, but I'm not sure how I would locate it.**

*My flat is in a hard water area, so this could be the result of a gradual limescale build up, but then the problems started very suddenly which makes me think this us unlikely.*

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Maybe a larger chunk of scale flaked off and plugged something up. Have you seen signs of scale in fixtures? Check a faucet aerator for scale plugging. You may need to back-flush.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it, emptying and refilling the cylinder seems to have worked something loose, and it's working perfectly again - thanks for the help.